# When i reload the page, the countdown reload to

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

How to keep time on the jquery.countdown plugin?

The countdown run correctly, but when i reload the page, the countdown reload to, and i want to keep the countdown when i reload, what i should do?

http://jsfiddle.net/wtkd/CUSnS/

Comment: It needs to persist somewhere, like in `localStorage` or a cookie.

Comment: How do you determine if you want to start counting from 0 or n seconds? Do you have some way of distinguishing between page opened first time and page refreshed via F5?

Comment: Well, since you're counting towards a past date, it'll assume the default 12 hours. Have a future date as your countdown target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its initialized after the DOM is ready, and therefore you cannot keep the remaining time, you can grab the current time of your server and, say `echo` it in a javascript variable and update the time of countdown.

Comment: You don't need a hidden input. This isn't an input from the user. Use the server-side language to generate the JavaScript variable which holds the time.

Answer (score 1):

You use Jan 1st 2012 as your countdown target (which has already passed) and then you check for this condition and count towards a point in time which is 12 hours from now. You need to count towards a fixed date if you want the countdown to work correctly, otherwise it will always start at 12:00:00. "Fixed date" means that you need to pass the date as a parameter or store it somehow.